# Talend -- Rest API call

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, talend, trustpilot

I am currently building an ETL job in Talend Open Studio, that calls an API to get data, the API call is [OAuth 2.0 Authorized](https://documentation-apidocumentation.trustpilot.com/authentication) with an access token which I have to get by passing some values that are Base 64 Encoded, I am struggling in the part of getting access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the linked docs

> To obtain a token you need **your** API Key, API Secret, Trustpilot username and password.

Then you call

```
Method: POST
https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/oauth/oauth-business-users-for-applications/accesstoken
```

With Headers:

```
Authorization: Basic [BASE64_ENCODED(API_KEY:API_SECRET)]
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Noting that `The KEY AND SECRET needs to be concatenated as follows KEY:SECRET and then base64 encoded`

---

You should get your token and encoded values **outside of Talend** (although, there probably is a base64 encoding processor).

For example, on Unix, `echo 'hello:world' | base64`

So, just use curl.

```bash
export TRUSTPILOT_TOKEN=$(echo "your-key:secret" | base64)
curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Basic ${TRUSTPILOT_TOKEN}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/oauth/oauth-business-users-for-applications/accesstoken
```

You may also need `-u username:password` option.

Then extract token from that response.

Then you can use Talend `tHttpRequest` to call other API endpoints listed in TrustPilot docs to call with `Authorization: Bearer ${token}` header.

Keep in mind, that your OAuth token can expire, and you'd need to re-run the POST command again.